# 3 pdf graphs on 1 page with text below

Tags: graphics, spacing

I am new to latex.
I have to prepare a one-page document (so float is not important).
I want to have 3 pdf graphs at the top of the page with 2 graphs centered on the first line and 1 graph centered below it.  I want the two lines of graphs to be as close together as possible, so that I can have as much text as possible below them.

I have a standard latex document.  Here is the current code for the graphs:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[trim = 40 0 0
150,clip=true,width=0.4\linewidth]{graphs/fig_succ_hazard_est} \quad %
\includegraphics[trim = 40 0 0
150,clip=true,width=0.4\linewidth]{graphs/fig_term_hazard_est}
\includegraphics[trim = 40 0 0
150,clip=true,width=0.4\linewidth]{graphs/fig_term_hazard_est}
\end{center}
```

The problem is the vertical spacing between the two lines of graphs.  It is too big.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks a lot.

All the best,
Bob

Comment: There shouldn't be much space, the default is 1pt. Put \fbox{} around your graphics to see their size.

Comment: In order to decrease the vertical spacing, you need to avoid using the `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment. Rather use `{\centering ...}`. Read [this blog entry](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/center-centering/) to gain some more insight.

Comment: You're right!!! Thank you so much for your help.  I need to trim the white from beneath the graphs.

Comment: @Ulrike: Please convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6):

(Originally posted as comments by Ulrike Fischer and Werner)

There shouldn't be much space, the default is 1pt. Put `\fbox` around your graphics to see their size.

In order to decrease the vertical spacing, you also need to avoid using the `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment. Rather use `{\centering ...}`. Read [this blog entry](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/center-centering/) to gain some more insight.